# Is there a way to add custom data per store

Tags: bigcommerce

I need to add additional validation to emails in registration process. so I will to add an app in external server to handle this using the API. But I wanna save custom settings data per store, to access it later from the app, this is to handle additional information without create other database.

is this possible ?